# アンドロイド開発のtween アニメーションについて

Tags: android, java, android-layout

アンドロイド開発で現在、簡単なアニメーションを作成しています。
 画面にtranslationとrotateのボタンと画像a1が表示され、ボタンを押すとそれぞれに対応して動作して機能しています。

質問1:rotateボタンに別の画像b1を設定、translarionボタンを押すと画像a1だけが表示され動作する。rotateボタンを押すと、画像b1だけが表示され、動作するような設定を教えていただければ、大変助かりますのでよろしくお願いします。

java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);


    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.trans);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          img.startAnimation(anim);

                       }
    });
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              img.startAnimation(anim);
        }

    });
}}
```

xml

```
  <ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ball"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"       
android:id="@+id/img"/>

/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Translate"


    android:id="@+id/btn1" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rotate"
        android:id="@+id/btn2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、rotateボタンをImageButtonに変更し、ImageViewのように画像をセットします。必要であれば、さらにandroid:backgroundで背景を透明にしたり、xmlで各状態別（タップ時、選択時、通常時など）の画像をまとめてセットすると良いでしょう。

その後、タップに合わせて他のビューを見た目上消したいのであれば、Javaのコード側からsetVisibilityでViewの可視状態を切り替えつつやれば良いかと思います。

setVisibility(View.GONE)

を設定すると対象のビューがレイアウトから消えます。ビューの位置関係を保ったまま消したい場合は

setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

を使用します。元に戻したい場合は

setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

を設定します。

Comment: setVisibility(View.VISIBLE 、setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
でできました

Comment: お役に立てたようでなによりです。